# Remove all trailing slashes at the end mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to remove ALL trailing slashes but only at the requested path, without dropping the query string:

```
http://example.com/test/page////////?filter=test
http://example.com/search//
```

to

```
http://example.com/test/page?filter=test
http://example.com/search
```

I couldn't find a working rule and I'm testing with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

I tried with the following and several combinations:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work because the left part is more greedy than the `/+` part. Will only match 1 slash!

If I use `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]`, it results in a redirect loop until the limit of redirects is reached, I need to replace this rule..

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/////////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)////////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)///////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)//////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)////$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)///$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)//$ $1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

But this does not redirect 301 if all slashes are removed before the last rule hits..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(/test/page)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: to match any path and remove trailing slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^(/.+?)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This will provide a non greedy match up until the first of one or more `/` that are anchored to the end of the string.

Comment: This only removes 1 slash: `http://example.com/test/page///?filter=test` to `http://example.com/test/page//?filter=test`

Comment: Where are you testing this? Works perfectly for me and there's no reason I can see how the regular expression could possibly behave like that.

Comment: I tested on the live server now and on the site provided in the question. This rule will redirect `url///` to `url//` to `url/` to `url` which is a redirect loop (you can see this with FireBug)

Comment: I wouldn't trust the site you provided, it doesn't appear to be behaving very well, and by their own admission it's buggy. Should work on the server. Like I said, there's no way that regex can be behaving like that if you typed it correctly. `$1` can't ever be anything except `/test/page`

Comment: Have implemented this here for you to see working: http://95.85.43.83/test/page/////////////?filter=1234

Comment: It's working on your server. I'll try again on mine, thx for the link

Comment: I know what the problem is,... My path is not fixed to `test/page`. It can be anything, so I'm using: `^(.*)/+$` - looks like `*` is more greedy than `/+`, so in `http://www.test.com/other/page/test///`, `^(.*)` matches `http://www.test.com/other/page/test//` and `/+$` matches the remaining `/`.